# Springdoc random api-docs generation

Tags: java, springdoc

I am looking to generate an api that take different content type.

The problem I am facing is that if I run several time my application I have different output documentation

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @Operation(summary = "GetMyData", operationId = "gettt",
        responses = @ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/vnd.something")))
    @GetMapping(produces = "application/vnd.something")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getSomethingElse() {
        return noContent().build();
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String get() {
        return "some text";
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public EntityModel<JsonResponse> getHal() {
        return EntityModel.of(new JsonResponse(),
            linkTo(MyRestController.class).slash("somelink").withSelfRel()
        );
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public JsonResponse getJson() {
        return new JsonResponse();
    }
}
```

It currently generate a wrong api-docs

```
"operationId": "gettt_1_1_1",
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "content": {
            "application/hal+json": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityModelJsonResponse"
                }
            },
            "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/JsonResponse"
                }
            },
            "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "description": "OK"
    },
    "204": {
        "content": {
            "application/hal+json": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityModelJsonResponse"
                }
            },
            "application/vnd.something": {},
            "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "description": "No Content"
    }
},
```

If I restart  my server without changing the code the following response is generated

```
"operationId": "gettt_1",
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "content": {
            "application/hal+json": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityModelJsonResponse"
                }
            },
            "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/JsonResponse"
                }
            },
            "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "description": "OK"
    },
    "204": {
        "content": {
            "application/vnd.something": {}
        },
        "description": "No Content"
    }
},
```

I would expect that restarting my server will always generate the same documentation

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the documentation?

- https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/springdoc-properties.html#swagger-ui-properties

You can use the swagger-ui properties, without having to override the standard way of sorting (operationsSorter and tagsSorter).

For example:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
```

If you want a an order on the server side, you can use OpenApiCustomiser, to sort the elements

This is a sample code that you can customize using Comparators, depending on the sorting logic you want:

Example, for alphabetical order sorting of schemas:

```java
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser sortSchemasAlphabetically() {
    return openApi -> {
        Map<String, Schema> schemas = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas();
        openApi.getComponents().setSchemas(new TreeMap<>(schemas));
    };
}
```

Example for sorting tags, in alphabetical order:

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser sortTagsAlphabetically() {
    return openApi -> openApi.setTags(openApi.getTags()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(tag -> StringUtils.stripAccents(tag.getName())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

You can have full control on the elements order, and you can sort them depending on your use case...

Comment: I will edit my question to be more specific but my issue is that the order of the method in my class change the "shape" (not only the order) of the documentation, some parts are missing.

Answer (score 1):

one other flag [mentioned here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/445#issuecomment-732988987):

```
springdoc:
 writer-with-order-by-keys
```